# dbms_scheduler jobs failing in Oracle 19

Tags: oracle

```
Our application  moved from oracle 11 to Oracle 19c in Azure cloud.

When I scheduled the same jobs what I had in oracle 11 on prem are failing in oracle 19.
```

The job calls a procedure in a package which loads a record type data into a table.

```
sample code is

BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'e_job',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           => 'BEGIN a_pkg.load_payload; END;',
   start_date           => TRUNC (SYSDATE) + (ROUND ( (SYSDATE - TRUNC (SYSDATE)) * 48) / 48),
   repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;BYMINUTE=25,55;',
   end_date             => NULL,
   enabled              => TRUE,
   comments             => 'Creates  Notifications');
END;



this is failing with 

ORA-06550: line 1, column 763:
PLS-00201: identifier 'a_pkg.load_payload' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 500:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


I tried few permissions like
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER TO PUBLIC;
```

GRANT EXECUTE ON 'PACKAGE' TO PUBLIC;

BOTH DID NOT WORK.

```
Thanks
```

Comment: why would you be adding grants to PUBLIC?  what schema is a_pkg under? try adding the schema to prefix the package name

Comment: Ask the DBA to `grant execute on [ownername].a_pkg to [jobowner]`. Also ensure the job owner has a synonym pointing to the [ownername].package, since you are not fully qualifying the package with a schema name. Lastly, make sure the package actually exists.

Comment: *Don't* make grants to `public`, especially for restricted system calls.